# How could I diagnose a computer (INTEL board with FreeBSD) that does want to acquire a DHCP address?

Tags: networking, dhcp, freebsd

I have a system that comprises 3 logic boards with 3 different CPUs (3 computers in one systems). They are all attached to a router that is connected to a wifi bridge.

Of these 3 boards, only 2 manage to acquire a DHCP address.

My INTEL board (the only INTEL of the 3), is running FreeBSD and is not able to acquire a DHCP address? nor setting to a static IP resolves networking.

Additionally, the /etc/resolv.conf file is being overwritten, so they are unable to set their DNS server.

I am not a networking expert. Any tips or questions will be valuable.

My first thought is that the firewall may be blocking specific hardware, may be filtering the mac address of the INTEL board (?) Could that be a possibility sense?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can check with tcpdump on the FreeBSD system, if the packets are leaving the interface.

Also check if you are seeing broadcasts on the interface.

You could also sniff on a computer connected directly to the NIC if you receive packets from the NIC.

If you are using DHCP on more than one interface, you have to modify the dhclient.conf to specify which interface should request the DNS server.

Comment: that is correct! this is what I have done. I thought I had documented this. dhclient broadcasts a request for IP on port 67 and wait for IP info from DHCP server on port 68 right?